# Bootstrap 4 Order div columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to reorder my divs in footer for tab and mob resolution, but can't get the social links bellow address block,can someone offer the solution why this is not working: Is it the problem that logo and social links are nested in the same div?

```
<footer class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end address-block">
                <p class="address-footer">
                    <em>Cyalk Cmunions Ltd</em><br>
                    Heate use<br>
                    Rans Lane<br>
                    Aybury<br>
                    Bus<br>
                    H9 8RT<br><br>

                    <span>Company registered number: 06416</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-2 col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column logof-block">
                <div class="logo-footer">
                    <img src="~/img/logo-footer-rgb-group.png" alt="logo-footer">
                </div>
                <div class="social-footer">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="bloggerw-icon" src="~/img/blogger.png" alt="blogger icon">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/cikcomms/">
                        <img class="facew-icon" src="~/img/facebook.png" alt="face icon">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="linkedinw-icon" src="~/img/linked-in.png" alt="linkedin icon">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="pinterestw-icon" src="~/img/pinterest.png" alt="pinterest icon">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/CitkComms?lang=en">
                        <img class="twitterw-icon" src="~/img/twitter.png" alt="twitter icon">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="youtubew-icon" src="~/img/youtube.png" alt="youtube icon">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="instagram-icon" src="~/img/instagram.png" alt="instragram icon">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end contactf-block">
                <p class="contact-footer">
                    New Business Sales   <em class="nr1f">03 2414 101</em><br />
                    Provisioning & Engineering   <em class="nr2f">33 2414 102</em><br />
                    Support   <em class="nr3f">0333 2414 103</em><br />
                    Accounts & Billing  <em class="nr4f">33 2414 104</em><br><br />

                    <span>Terms, Conditions and Complaints</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>
```

////////////////
/////////order divs for smaller screens////////

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .logo-footer {
        order: 1;
    }
    .address-block {
        order: 2;
    }
    .social-footer {
        order: 3;
    }
    .contactf-block {
        order: 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: display: flex;width: 100%;

Comment: *"Is it the problem that logo and social links are nested in the same div"* - yes

Comment: can you add a running code spin-net for that ?n yeah they have to be in the same div .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything has to be in the same div, whether that's a .row or a .col is your choice.

You could also use [bootstraps reorder classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#reordering), which are responsive.